# Use web service on different machine(how to port the service and client)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio

i have created a web service using .net (c#).I have a server program and a client program.Which is working fine in my local system.(Even if i run client exe)

But when i have given my client exe to some other system (which are connected through LAN with my system) the service is not getting processed. My web service continuously running(server) on my Machine.

I followed http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2010/09/create-simple-web-service-in-visual.html link to create server and client(web service).

So now the problem is how can i port my client or how other's can use my webserver?

How to fix this error i tried using Add reference option but i don't know where,what and how to add... where is that assembly?

Or what else i can try?

Comment: Well why do you have `using WebServiceTest.localhost;`? What made you expect that to be valid?

Comment: i want to use a web service and for that in client program in project i have added "Add Web Reference" and there i have added my service as per the link given below 
http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2010/09/create-simple-web-service-in-visual.html

Comment: does the service running or building?

Comment: @Badshah: Well that article doesn't include a *namespace* containing `localhost` - why did you add that?

Comment: yes its running in other window countinuosly

Comment: @JonSkeet there he used "TestWeb" while adding i used "localhost" that's the reason.Do i need to give every thing same?

Comment: @Badshah: Well you should only use what's *actually in the reference*. When you added the web reference, that should have generated some proxy code - you should look at what namespace that proxy code uses.

Comment: when i added the reference i had given "localhost" as a reference name

Comment: @JonSkeet hey now i just modified my source and its working fine....i have replaced my **WebServiceTest** to my project name i.e. **ConsoleApplication** now there is no error but i did not understand the reason....is like "local host" definition was present under the project name's namespace?

Comment: @Badshah: It's important to understand that namespaces aren't the same as references. Again, look in the generated proxy code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24693/discussion-between-badshah-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: where i can see proxy code?location?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this, but I seem to remember that if you expand the web reference, you can view the generated code.